# Blending multiple images with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv

What is the way to blend multiple images with OpenCV using python? I came across the following snippet:

```
img = cv2.addWeighted(mountain, 0.3, dog, 0.7, 0)
```

on https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html

that shows a way to blend 2 images `mountain` and `dog`. What if I want to blend more than 2  images? How could I do this?

Comment: What about using the result of a blended image and blend it with another one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This:

blendedImage = weight_1 * image_1 + weight_2 * image_2 + ... + weight_n * image_n

Comment: make sure that all weights sum up to 1

Answer (score 4):

You can blend all of your images by blending according to follwoing sequence:

1. Blend the first two images
2. Take the result and blend it with the next image
3. and so forth

```
for idx, img in enumerate(imgs):
    if idx == 1:
        first_img = img
        continue
    else:
        second_img = img
        first_img = cv2.addWeighted(first_img, 0.5, second_img, 0.5, 0)
```

You might have a problem with the weights of each image, but this is another issues. To achieve an equal weigth for all images you can use the index to calculate the appropriate portion:

```
for idx, img in enumerate(imgs):
    if idx == 1:
        first_img = img
        continue
    else:
        second_img = img
        second_weight = 1/(idx+1)
        first_weight = 1 - second_weight
        first_img = cv2.addWeighted(first_img, first_weight, second_img, second_weight, 0)
```

Comment: Ideally you would want every image to have a partial contribution corresponding to the number of images being blend (in this case 1/9) not a half.

Comment: I think of a counter variable, which is used to caluculate the right portion.

Comment: Nice work. Some folk may be interested in this article https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-averaging-noise.htm which illustrates the averaging, specifically in the section **AVERAGING IMAGES IN PHOTOSHOP USING LAYERS**

Comment: @SimonFink The algo is still not doing what would be expected. First image should contribute with weight of 1/9, then when adding with others, you take the first one (weight 1) and every other with fixed weight of 1/9.

Comment: @Croolman If you have 1 layer, you use all of it (100%). If you have 2 layers, you want the bottom layer at 100% and the second layer at 50% (1/2) over the top, then you'll have half of each in the final result. If you have 3 layers, you take the top layer at 33% (1/3) and then other 2/3 is what you got from a 2-layer image previously, i.e. half of each of the bottom and first layer and as that is occupying the remaining 2/3, that will correspond to 1/3 of each of the bottom 2 layers. So the proportion you want of each new layer N is 1/(N+1).

Comment: Taking the 1st example. If you have image of type uchar (max 255) and you blend two layers with 100 % of the first one and 50 % of the second one, you might bump into unnecessary overflow.

Comment: In my approach, i want to have all the images equally weighted. So in the first blend it splits up to `1/2` for each image. In the second loop, weigths will be `2/3` and `1/3`. As the first two images have a total weigth of `2/3` and from the previos blend a weight of `1/2` each, they end up also having a portion of `1/2 * 2/3 = 1/3`. This propagetes throught all the loop executions.

Comment: To be more precise: In my approach, i want to have all the images equally weighted. So in the first blend it splits up to `1/2` for each image. In the second loop, weigths will be `2/3` for the first (already blended image) and `1/3` for the second image. As the first two images have a total weigth of `2/3` and from the previos blend a weight of `1/2` each, they end up also having a portion of `1/2 * 2/3 = 1/3`. This behaviour will be continue by blending new images. In the final loop you have a weight of `8/9` for all previous 8 blended images (with equal weight) and `1/9` for the last image.

Comment: start with a black image A and your N input images B1, B2, ... B9: addweighted 1 x A + 1/N x B1 to destination A; addWeighted 1x A + 1/N x B2 to destination A; and so on. But using addWeighted here is probably slower than just using it just like A = A + 1/N x B_i (at least for C++ cv::Mat, not sure about numpy) because of unneded 1 x A multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Python code to blend multiple images in a list. I used the basic formulation from Shamsheer's answer.

First, let's get three images.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

dim = (425, 425)

apple = mpimg.imread('apple.jpg')
apple = cv2.resize(apple, dim)

banana = mpimg.imread('banana.jpg')
banana = cv2.resize(banana, dim)

orange = mpimg.imread('orange.jpg')
orange = cv2.resize(orange, dim)

_ = plt.imshow(apple)
_ = plt.show()

_ = plt.imshow(banana)
_ = plt.show()

_ = plt.imshow(orange)
_ = plt.show()
```

Here are the images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now let's blend them together equally. Since there are three images, the fraction of each image's contribution to the final output is 0.333.

```py
def blend(list_images): # Blend images equally.

    equal_fraction = 1.0 / (len(list_images))

    output = np.zeros_like(list_images[0])

    for img in list_images:
        output = output + img * equal_fraction

    output = output.astype(np.uint8)
    return output

list_images = [apple, banana, orange]
output = blend(list_images)

_ = plt.imshow(output)
```

And here is the result:

[image]